# RosAria_pose orientation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using /RosAria/pose to get position (x,y) and orientation (w).

Does anyone knows how to convert the w to grades?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63009/rosaria_pose-orientation/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You mean degrees probably

You need a quaternion to degrees conversion tool. Or use for instance the [bullet class](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/RotationMethods).

edit:

```
  tf::Pose pose;
  tf::poseMsgToTF(odom->pose.pose, pose);
  double yaw_angle = tf::getYaw(pose.getRotation());
```

from [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/41233/how-to-understand-robot-orientation-from-quaternion-yaw-angle/)

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-05-20**:
Aha :), sorry for the mistake, yea, I mean degrees, do you have a piece of code I can use? :)

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-05-22**:
Thank you for the piece of code :)